# Updating Nested Data

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to update nested data in a D3 application where the nesting is greater than 2 levels deep.  Let's start out with my code.

Here's the jQuery handler when the page is ready.

```
$(function () {
    var data = createDataSet();
    updateD3(data);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var dataAgain = createDataSet();
        updateD3(dataAgain);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Here's the update function.

```
function updateD3(data) {
    var level1 = d3
        .select('body')
        .selectAll('div.level-1')
        .data(data);

    // UPDATE existing data.
    level1
        .text(function (d) { return d.nameLevelOne + '-'; })
        .selectAll('div.level-2')
        .data(function (d) { return d.valuesLevelOne; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.nameLevelTwo + '-'; })
        .selectAll('div.level-3')
        .data(function (d) { return d.valuesLevelTwo; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.nameLevelThree + ' ' + d.count + '-'; });

    // CREATE new data.
    level1
    .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'level-1')
        .text(function (d) { return d.nameLevelOne; })
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(function (d) { return d.valuesLevelOne; })
    .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'level-2')
        .text(function (d) { return d.nameLevelTwo; })
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(function (d) { return d.valuesLevelTwo; })
    .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'level-3')
        .text(function (d) { return d.nameLevelThree + ' ' + d.count; });

    // REMOVE deleted data.
    level1
    .exit()
        .selectAll('div')
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .remove();
}
```

Here's the data creation function, which also documents the structure of the data.

```
function createDataSet() {
        return [
        {
            nameLevelOne: 'A',
            valuesLevelOne: [{
                nameLevelTwo: 'AA',
                valuesLevelTwo: [
                    {
                        nameLevelThree: 'AAA',
                        count: Math.random() * 100
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            nameLevelOne: 'B',
            valuesLevelOne: [{
                nameLevelTwo: 'BB',
                valuesLevelTwo: [
                    {
                        nameLevelThree: 'BBB',
                        count: Math.random() * 100
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    ];
}
```

When I run this code in the browser, the first `updateD3()` call is perfect.  It shows this:

```
A
AA
AAA 24.26636815071106
B
BB
BBB 37.17236865777522
```

When 5 seconds pass and a new data set is created and passed into another call to `updateD3()`, the output changes to this:

```
A-
B-
```

This is NOT the output I expected.  I did not expect any part of the DOM to be destroyed. Essentially, I expected the numbers by `AAA` and `BBB` to be updated to new values.

**Why is this happening?  How do I only update the DOM with the updated data?**

I have looked and looked around the Internet for solutions but nearly every example of "nested" data is actually only 2 levels deep, or if the data is more than 2 levels deep the example has no code demonstrating updating data.

Any help is greatly appreciated, especially after around 6 hours of beating my head against the wall over this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the selection at each level once instead of multiple times, i.e. something like

```
var level1 = selection.data(...);
level1.enter()...
level1.exit()...
level1....

var level2 = level1.selectAll(...).data(...);
level2.enter()...
level2.exit()...
level2...

var level3 = level2.selectAll(...).data(...);
// etc
```

When you're making the selections and binding data multiple times, the selections affect each other and you get wrong elements in the selections.

Comment: What is each `.data(...)` call supposed to be given?  I'm confident the `level1` call should be given the raw data, but are the calls for `level2` and `level3` given functions that return `d.valuesLevelOne` and `d.valuesLevelTwo` respectively?

Comment: I've gotten a bit further now.  I didn't catch that that you must bind the data, then `enter`, then `exit`, then `update` **per level**.  The only problem now is that if I change the data and do an update, the `B`, `BB` and `BBB` sections disappear.  Any thoughts?  Here's a working version of my code at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/r2xt0w2k/

Comment: You were selecting just `div`s, so actually all the nested `div`s in the top-level selection. You can use the class names you assign in the selector to fix that. I've also simplified your code a bit https://jsfiddle.net/r2xt0w2k/1/

Comment: Thank you, Lars.  That helps.  The only final question I have is this: in your edit to the jsfiddle, it still appears as though the DOM is being destroyed and recreated for the `AA`, `AAA`, `BB`, and `BBB` sections on every update.  Is this how D3 works, or is there a way to only update the DOM (not destroy it)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "destroy the DOM". The elements aren't all deleted and then readded if that's what you mean.

Comment: Take a look at my updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/r2xt0w2k/2/.  When it starts, the `AAA` and `BBB` fadesin at first, as expected, then fade out as expected.  But then as the setInterval() keeps running, the `AAA` and `BBB` lines immediately disappear, then fade back in.  I always expect them to fade out, not immediately disappear.  That suggests to me that the `AAA` and `BBB` lines are destroyed-- they are not respecting the `.transition()` rules for `level3`.

Comment: If parts of the DOM were being removed, they would appear in the exit selections. I'm not sure what's going on in your example. It works without the initial transition https://jsfiddle.net/r2xt0w2k/3/

Comment: Lars, thank you for continuing to provide assistance.  While https://jsfiddle.net/r2xt0w2k/3/ achieves the desired effect, I can watch in Chrome's dev tools how the level-3 div is replaced with a new one each time.  What if I wanted the opacity be a new value that comes from my data each time?  And what if I wanted to transition from the current opacity value to the next one?

Comment: You could get the opacity in a function from the data, see the comment I've added https://jsfiddle.net/r2xt0w2k/4/

Comment: However, with the given code, the opacity would always start at zero and then transition to `d.opacity`, wouldn't it?  How could it transition from the last opacity value to the next?  Do I need to track the last opacity value myself?

Comment: No, you should be able to just remove the first transition and initialise new elements to some opacity.